# Google Maps API -> OpenGLES crash

Tags: ios, google-maps, crash-log

Log is pasted from Crashlytics. Crash happens very often, to many users and as far as I can see it is independent from the device/iOS version. I can't find any fault in my code, it seems like pure library problem. Is it Google Maps API bug? What can I do to fix it or should I fill some bug report on Google API page..?

Crashlog:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000001


libGPUSupportMercury.dylib  
gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient + 9

libGPUSupportMercury.dylib  
gldCreateContext

GLEngine    
gliCreateContextWithShared

OpenGLES    
-[EAGLContext initWithAPI:properties:] + 524

OpenGLES    
-[EAGLContext initWithAPI:sharedWithCompute:] + 142

!MYAPP! 
-[GMSIOSGLContext initWithAPI:]

!MYAPP! 
gmscore::renderer::GMSIOSGLContextPool::GMSIOSGLContextPool()

!MYAPP! 
___ZN7gmscore8renderer13GLContextPool16GetGLContextPoolEv_block_invoke

libdispatch.dylib   
_dispatch_client_callout + 22

libdispatch.dylib   
dispatch_once_f + 46

!MYAPP! 
gmscore::renderer::GLContextPool::GetGLContextPool()

!MYAPP! 
gmscore::renderer::GLScopedContextFromPool::GLScopedContextFromPool()

!MYAPP! 
-[GMSVectorMapSharedResourceCache init]

!MYAPP!     
__43-[GMSAsyncInitServices sharedInitWithSync:]_block_invoke

!MYAPP!     
-[GMSAsyncInitServices sharedInitWithSync:]

!MYAPP!     
-[GMSAsyncInitServices initSync]

!MYAPP!     
+[GMSServices sharedServicesSync]

!MYAPP!     
-[GMSGeocoder initWithConnection:]

!MYAPP!     
+[GMSGeocoder geocoder]

!MYAPP!     
AClass.m line 64
-[AClass doSomething:]
```

Where aClass doSomething is moreover like:

```
- (void)doSomething {
    [[GMSGeocoder geocoder] reverseGeocodeCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(_latitude, _longitude) 
                                   completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse* response, NSError* error) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I've filed a bug with google https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7178&thanks=7178&ts=1411912716. There is a related issue reported earlier https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&groupby=&sort=&id=6470#makechanges