# App crashes at gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, ios8

I am seeing new crashes specific to app running on iOS 8. Couldn't figure out what the issue is, couldn't reproduce the issue. Happens at App StartUp, and App doesn't call OpenGL ES functions directly.

`InitialViewController` `viewDidAppear` method line # 92 I initiate a segue from storyboard by: `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:segueIdentifier sender:self];` where `self` is `InitialViewController` class.

**Stacktrace:**

```
Thread: Unknown Name (Crashed)
0     libGPUSupportMercury.dylib            0x28c5c8fe gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient + 10
1     libGPUSupportMercury.dylib            0x28c5d249 gldCreateContext + 206
2     GLEngine                              0x248a093b gliCreateContextWithShared + 600
3     OpenGLES                              0x2497cab3 -[EAGLContext initWithAPI:properties:] + 404
4     CoreImage                             0x225ecb8b ___ZN2CI11can_use_gpuEv_block_invoke + 140
5     libdispatch.dylib                     0x2fbb98b7 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
6     libdispatch.dylib                     0x2fbba4fb dispatch_once_f + 60
7     CoreImage                             0x225ecafb _ZN2CI11can_use_gpuEv + 96
8     CoreImage                             0x2256ac79 +[CIContext contextWithOptions:] + 186
9     CoreUI                                0x27bdc837 CreateSharedCIContext + 76
10   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x2fd1ddcf __pthread_once_handler + 48
11   libsystem_platform.dylib               0x2fd16867 _os_once + 40
12   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x2fd1bf8b pthread_once + 48
13   CoreUI                                 0x27bdc7d9 +[CUIShapeEffectStack sharedCIContext] + 26
14   CoreUI                                 0x27be3af7 -[CUICatalog imageByStylingImage:stylePresetName:styleConfiguration:foregroundColor:scale:] + 80
15   UIKit                                  0x256c89db -[UIImage _imageWithStylePresets:withTintColor:] + 540
16   UIKit                                  0x25456875 -[UIImageView _setImageViewContents:] + 1074
17   UIKit                                  0x25455fb5 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 70
18   UIKit                                  0x25747db9 -[UIImageView _updateImageViewForOldImage:newImage:] + 674
19   UIKit                                  0x254559c7 -[UIImageView setImage:] + 264
20   UIKit                                  0x254f01b1 -[UINavigationBar _updateBackIndicatorImage] + 346
21   UIKit                                  0x254d4143 -[UINavigationBar layoutSubviews] + 2480
22   UIKit                                  0x25446b37 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 512
23   QuartzCore                             0x24e6eccd -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 134
24   QuartzCore                             0x24e6a6b5 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 358
25   UIKit                                  0x25459183 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 136
26   UIKit                                  0x25455fb5 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 70
27   UIKit                                  0x254d2fc5 -[UINavigationController _positionNavigationBarHidden:edge:initialOffset:] + 786
28   UIKit                                  0x254d2c63 -[UINavigationController _positionNavigationBarHidden:edge:] + 200
29   UIKit                                  0x254cf875 -[UINavigationController loadView] + 246
30   UIKit                                  0x254493d9 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 66
31   UIKit                                  0x2544935d -[UIViewController view] + 22
32   UIKit                                  0x254f1faf -[UIViewController shouldAutorotate] + 24
33   UIKit                                  0x2552bbd7 -[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentationInWindow:fromInterfaceOrientation:] + 248
34   UIKit                                  0x2552a2b9 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:] + 2118
35   UIKit                                  0x2572be1f -[UIViewController _windowControllerBasedPresentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 4896
36   UIKit                                  0x2572c4ab __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 256
37   UIKit                                  0x25529243 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 192
38   UIKit                                  0x2572c63f -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] + 28
39   MyAppName                              0x00082901 -[InitialViewController viewDidAppear:] (InitialViewController.m:92)
40   UIKit                                  0x2545ed5f -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 500
41   UIKit                                  0x254c322f -[UIViewController _executeAfterAppearanceBlock] + 52
42   UIKit                                  0x254c31bd _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 306
43   UIKit                                  0x2543f127 _afterCACommitHandler + 484
44   CoreFoundation                         0x21f725cd __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
45   CoreFoundation                         0x21f6fc8b __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 276
46   CoreFoundation                         0x21f70093 __CFRunLoopRun + 912
47   CoreFoundation                         0x21ebe621 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 474
48   CoreFoundation                         0x21ebe433 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
49   GraphicsServices                       0x2926c0a9 GSEventRunModal + 134
50   UIKit                                  0x254a8809 UIApplicationMain + 1438
51   MyAppName                              0x00074329 main (main.m:36)
52   libdyld.dylib                          0x2fbd9aaf start + 0
```

Can someone please help me find what the root cause for this issue is.

Comment: Similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919665/mysterious-crash-on-ios-8. Not exactly the same backtrace, though. Both happen during `gldCreateContext()`.

Comment: This one looks like the same backtrace, at least the top few frames: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135185/google-maps-api-opengles-crash.

Comment: As per one of the engineers on Apple dev forum "Please Report a Bug with a project that reproduces the issue. From the back trace it appears that you may be specifying a custom back indicator image on your navigation bars."

Comment: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/246744?tstart=0 "But either way this is an Apple Bug to fix, the workaround itself is fairly heavyweight (assuming it works, which I'm not certain of)."

Comment: @0x8badf00d I am also getting this issue, it started happening recently. Not sure what the problem is

Comment: I'm getting a similar stack trace (at least same top few lines) when setting a frame on a UIButton that has both and image and a tintColor. Crashes seem to happen when app is in background state. Can't reproduce it in a sample app, but am seeing enough of these crashes in analytics that it's a problem worth fixing. Also confined to older devices, mostly iPhone 5 and earlier.

Answer (score 11):

Application will be terminated if it attempts to execute OpenGL ES commands in the background.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1766/_index.html

Comment: As I have mentioned in my question, "App doesn't call OpenGL ES functions directly."

Comment: then it must be some type of library you are using?

Comment: Probably AdMob or something in a Webview using WebGL