# How to read and understand the report from Crashlytics

Tags: crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have a Swift Application, when app is run, sometimes app is crashed. I have received log report about Crash App from Crashlytics but I don't understand log report.

Please help me: How to read and understand report from Crashlytics in order to find line code is error.

My report from Crashlytics:

```
**Crashed: com.apple.main-thread**

**EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000001**

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread

0  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib     6691807120 gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient + 12

1  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib     6691811136 gpusSubmitDataBuffers + 172

2  GLEngine                       6603264500 gliPresentViewES_Exec + 196

3  GLEngine                       6603264248 gliPresentViewES + 84

4  OpenGLES                       6603324504 -[EAGLContext presentRenderbuffer:] + 72

5  SpriteKit                      6615201312 -[SKView renderContent] + 228

6  SpriteKit                      6615188728 __29-[SKView setUpRenderCallback]_block_invoke + 64

7  SpriteKit                      6615369448 -[SKDisplayLink _callbackForNextFrame:] + 272

8  QuartzCore                     6610051640 CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 32

9  QuartzCore                     6610051280 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 324

10 IOKit                          6557291632 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 376

11 CoreFoundation                 6538358212 __CFMachPortPerform + 180

12 CoreFoundation                 6538443348 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56

13 CoreFoundation                 6538443188 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 436

14 CoreFoundation                 6538434868 __CFRunLoopRun + 1640

15 CoreFoundation                 6537564884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396

16 GraphicsServices               6699431676 GSEventRunModal + 168

17 UIKit                          6617247552 UIApplicationMain + 1488

18 NiftyCat                       4296456952 main (AppDelegate.swift:11)

19 libdyld.dylib                  6844000776 start + 4
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App crashes at gpus\_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952409/app-crashes-at-gpus-returnnotpermittedkillclient)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to Symbolicate your Build to understand your Crash.

To do this in Crashlytics: you must add a "New Run Script Phase". this is the "+" Sign on the Build Phases of your target.

The Script goes like this:

"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" {YOUR-APP_ID_AT-FABRIC}

If you Installed Fabric using PODS.

Hope this helps ;-)

Cheers